# How to clone lines with a specific condition?

Tags: python, r

I have some hyperlinks in a text file. I want to compare the link on first line to next adjacent line and create links as per number?.
For example,

Consider below adjacent links

```
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/4/
```

Here the output file will be:

```
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/2/
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/3/
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/4/
```

Similarly I need to do for other lines....

Example input:

```
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/4/
https://gp.to/ab/563/dimp-02-07-2023/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/3/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/2/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/5/
```

Example output:

```
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/2/
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/3/
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/4/
https://gp.to/ab/563/dimp-02-07-2023/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/2/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/3/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/2/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/2/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/3/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/4/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/5/
```

I tried..

```
# Function to extract the number from a URL
def extract_number(url):
    parts = url.split('/')
    for part in parts[::-1]:
        if part.isdigit():
            return int(part)
    return None

# Read the input file
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()

output_lines = []

# Iterate through the input lines and generate output lines
for i in range(len(lines)):
    current_url = lines[i].strip()
    output_lines.append(current_url)

    if i + 1 < len(lines):
        next_url = lines[i + 1].strip()
        current_number = extract_number(current_url)
        next_number = extract_number(next_url)

        if current_number is not None and next_number is not None:
            for num in range(current_number + 1, next_number):
                new_url = current_url.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + '/' + str(num) + '/'
                output_lines.append(new_url)

# Write the output to a file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.writelines(output_lines)
```

But I did not get desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another alternative. It assumes that order is relevant, so if the same url (or base of it, sans the trailing number) is found with intermediate different URLs, it will be "new".

```r
library(dplyr)
tibble(url=vec) %>%
  mutate(
    urlbase = sub("/\\d+/?$", "/", url),
    num = as.integer(sub("/$", "", stringr::str_extract(url, "(?<=/)(\\d+)/?$"))),
    grp = consecutive_id(urlbase)
  ) %>%
  group_by(grp, urlbase) %>%
  mutate(
    num = if (n() > 1) coalesce(num, row_number()) else num
  ) %>%
  reframe(
    num = seq.int(max(coalesce(num, 1L))),
    url = paste0(urlbase, if_else(num == 1L, "", paste0(as.character(num), "/")))
  )
# # A tibble: 15 × 4
#      grp urlbase                                    num url                                       
#    <int> <chr>                                    <int> <chr>                                     
#  1     1 https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/       1 https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/    
#  2     1 https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/       2 https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/2/  
#  3     1 https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/       3 https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/3/  
#  4     1 https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/       4 https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/4/  
#  5     2 https://gp.to/ab/563/dimp-02-07-2023/        1 https://gp.to/ab/563/dimp-02-07-2023/     
#  6     3 https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/     1 https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/  
#  7     3 https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/     2 https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/2/
#  8     3 https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/     3 https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/3/
#  9     4 https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/       1 https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/    
# 10     4 https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/       2 https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/2/  
# 11     5 https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/      1 https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/   
# 12     5 https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/      2 https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/2/ 
# 13     5 https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/      3 https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/3/ 
# 14     5 https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/      4 https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/4/ 
# 15     5 https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/      5 https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/5/
```

---

Data

```r
vec <- c("https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/", "https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/4/", "https://gp.to/ab/563/dimp-02-07-2023/", "https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/", "https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/3/", "https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/", "https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/2/", "https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/", "https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/5/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way in R how we could approach the problem. We create a function `extrapolate_link` and use `purrr::accumulate` on it. Then we `unlist` the results.

```r
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)

z <- "https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/
https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/4/
https://gp.to/ab/563/dimp-02-07-2023/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/3/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/2/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/
https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/5/"


extrapolate_link <- function(x, y) {
  x_ln <- length(x)
  if (x_ln > 1) {
    x <- x[x_ln]
  }
  res <- sub(pattern = x, replacement = "", x = y) |> 
    readr::parse_number()
  
  if (!is.null(attr(res, "problems"))){
    return(y)
  }
  if (is.numeric(res)) {
    return(paste0(x, rep(seq(4)[-1]), "/"))
  }
  stop("something went wrong.")
}


str_split(z, pattern = "\n") |>
  unlist() |> 
  accumulate(.f = extrapolate_link) |> 
  unlist()

#>  [1] "https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/"    
#>  [2] "https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/2/"  
#>  [3] "https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/3/"  
#>  [4] "https://gp.to/ab/394/las69-02-09-2020/4/"  
#>  [5] "https://gp.to/ab/563/dimp-02-07-2023/"     
#>  [6] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/"  
#>  [7] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/2/"
#>  [8] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/3/"
#>  [9] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/omegs-02-07-2023/4/"
#> [10] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/"    
#> [11] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/2/"  
#> [12] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/3/"  
#> [13] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/lis-22-04-2018/4/"  
#> [14] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/"   
#> [15] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/2/" 
#> [16] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/3/" 
#> [17] "https://gp.to/ab/39443/madi-22-04-2018/4/"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>